# Play video from gallery in iOS using cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, video, filepicker.io

Hi am using [Filepicker Plugin](https://github.com/albertut/cordova-filepicker) for get images and videos from gallery in my `iOS cordova application`.

Am getting a temporary path of image and video from the plugin when we pick image or video from the gallery.
I displayed the image in the image tag but video is not playing. It seems the temporary path will-not played. 
Is there any solution for getting `actual path for play the video` or is there any `plugin for iOS to convert temporary path to actual path`?

Please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had the same issue. The temporary path that you have is the url to the application cache folder. I solved this issue on my app by saving the file selected locally and using the resultant path thereafter.

I use the following code to solve this.

```
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, failrequestFileSystem);

function gotFS(fileSystem) {
    fileSystem.root.getDirectory("vids", {create: true}, gotDir);
}

function gotDir(dirEntry) {
    dirEntry.getFile("video.MOV", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFile);
}

function gotFile(fileEntry) {
    var localPath = fileEntry.fullPath;
    var localUrl = fileEntry.toURL();

    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
    var uri = encodeURI(<temp path that u have>);
    fileTransfer.download(
        uri,
        localUrl,
        function(entry) {
            uralToUse = entry.nativeURL; // use this url to play video
            var videoNode = document.querySelector('video');
            videoNode.src = entry.toNativeURL();
        },
        function(error) { }
    );
}

function failrequestFileSystem(error) { }
```

Cheers.