# how to select the video from gallery in phonegap?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, video, phonegap-plugins

Please help me any one how to select only the video from the gallery in android and iOS in cordova 
I am tried this [click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753364/impossible-to-pick-video-from-gallery-library-phonegap-cordova/33051818#33051818) for select the video from media but it not working for me...

```
var pictureSource; 
var destinationType; 
var mediaType;

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
 pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
 destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
 mediaType = navigator.camera.MediaType;
}

navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
  destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
  mediaType: mediaType.VIDEO,
  sourceType: source
});

function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
  console.log(imageURI);
}

function onFail(message) {
  console.log(message); 
}
```

i am used this same code to implement in my app but it can't come....

Answer (score 4):

You can try the snippet below:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 100,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    mediaType: Camera.MediaType.VIDEO
  });
```

Not that the `mediaType` can be:

```
Camera.MediaType = { 
    PICTURE: 0,             // allow selection of still pictures only. DEFAULT. Will return format specified via DestinationType
    VIDEO: 1,               // allow selection of video only, WILL ALWAYS RETURN FILE_URI
    ALLMEDIA : 2            // allow selection from all media types
```

For reference read [this](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html).

Comment: For Android its Working fine but i tried in iOS it can't working.. @Rashwan L

Comment: Weird.. Have you tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31024865/5576310)?

Comment: Ok try it and I´ll update my answer afterwords, but my current code in my answer should be working. Good luck @HariNarayanan

Comment: try for ios https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file and resolveLocalFileSystemURL method for correct path for video file

Comment: Have you found any solution for this yet @HariNarayanan? Did the above comment help you?

Comment: Still Not @Rashwan L i am able to select the video from gallery but i can not able record the video from camera.

Comment: @HariNarayanan, have you tried [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture)?